# Need correct macro coding to attach documents a/o files to Outlook from Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel, outlook, email-attachments

I have a macro that searches a contact list that pulls data from a list of contacts in Excel, and prepares an email to be sent in Outlook.

Most of this macro works successfully.  I am almost finished.

I also need it to search a folder (using the filename to be entered in cell A8) and attach the appropriate file to the emails.

(Folder path: C:\Users\SERGIL\Desktop\VATS )

```
Below is the code I have thus far:

    Public Sub SendEmails()
        Const cSUBJECT As String = "C2"
        Const cBODY As String = "C3"
        Const cSTART_ROW_INDEX As String = "C4"
        Const cEND_ROW_INDEX As String = "C5"

        Const cMAIL_TO_COLUMN As String = "G" ' The column with the email addresses in it
        Const cCOMPANY_NAME_COLUMN As String = "B" ' The column with the Vendor/Company Names in it


        'Put as many email addresses here as you want, just seperate them with a semicolon
        Const cCC_EMAIL_ADDRESSES As String = "C6"

        Const cFROM_ADDRESS As String = "C7"

        Dim iRowCount As Integer
        Dim iEndRow As Integer

        'Grab the current open worksheet object
        Dim oSheet As Worksheet
        Set oSheet = ActiveSheet

        iRowCount = oSheet.Range(cSTART_ROW_INDEX).Value2 ' Get the Start Value
        iEndRow = oSheet.Range(cEND_ROW_INDEX).Value2 ' Get the End Value

        Dim dBatchStart As Date
        Dim dBatchEnd As Date
        Dim sVendorName As String
        Dim sEmail As String
        Dim sSubject As String
        Dim sBody As String

        'Outlook must already be open, attach to the open instance
        Dim oOutlook As Outlook.Application
        Set oOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")

        'Declare a new draft email object
        Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem

        'Start iterating through all the rows of mail, creating a new draft each loop
        Do Until iRowCount = (iEndRow + 1)

            'Actually instantiate the new draft email object
            Set oMail = oOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

            'Display the draft on screen to the user can see and validate it
            oMail.Display

            'Set the TO address based on the data in the sheet
            oMail.To = oSheet.Range(cMAIL_TO_COLUMN & iRowCount).Value2

            'Get the subject, also, substitute the tags for Company and Start Date with the values in the sheet
            sSubject = oSheet.Range(cSUBJECT).Value2
            sSubject = Replace(sSubject, "<DATE FOR THAT VENDOR GROUP>", Format(dBatchStart, "Long Date"))
            sSubject = Replace(sSubject, "<COMPANY>", oSheet.Range(cCOMPANY_NAME_COLUMN & iRowCount).Value2)

            'Now insert the formatted subject into the draft email
            oMail.Subject = sSubject

            'Get the Body, substitute the tags for Start Date and End Date with the values in the sheet
            sBody = oSheet.Range(cBODY).Value2

            'Now insert the formatted Body into the draft email
            oMail.HTMLBody = sBody

            'Now add attachments
            oMail.HTMLBody = sBody

            'Set the CC address based on the Constant at the top
            oMail.CC = oSheet.Range(cCC_EMAIL_ADDRESSES).Value2

            oMail.Save
            'Set the actual sender of the name. It won't display for the user, but will actually sent as that address
            oMail.SentOnBehalfOfName = oSheet.Range(cFROM_ADDRESS).Value2
            oMail.Save


            'The draft mail item is now complete.
            'The from address will need to be changed manually.
            'The user will need to actually send the email once reviewed.

            iRowCount = iRowCount + 1
        Loop

         With objMail
             .Attachments.Add rngAttach.Value
             .Display 'Instead of .Display, you can use .Send to send the email _
                         or .Save to save a copy in the drafts folder
         End With


    End Sub
```

-- I am receiving an error with this segment of the code:

```
  With objMail
         .Attachments.Add rngAttach.Value
         .Display 'Instead of .Display, you can use .Send to send the email _
                     or .Save to save a copy in the drafts folder
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Add method of the Attachments class accepts four parameters. The Source parameter (the first one) should be a file (represented by the full file system path with a file name) or an Outlook item that constitutes the attachment.

It seems you need to replace the *rngAttach.Value* statement with a valid parameter (a file or Outlook object).

Comment: Thank you very much.  I am actually helping another party or trying to).  I won't pretend to know the right way to apply this, but I'm sure this will help.